# Get resulting LINQ expression from LINQ Dynamic WHERE

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the next code in LINQ Dynamic:

```
var list = server1Products.Where("Field1 = @0 AND Field2 >= @2", arg1, arg2).ToList();
```

I need to get the **resulting LINQ Expression** after using the LINQ Dynamic WHERE, **so use it in another list**.

How to get this resulting LINQ Expression?

```
.Where("Field1 = @0 AND Field2 >= @2", arg1, arg2)
```

**Example:**

```
// get the LINQ expression from WHERE
var conditions = GetExpresionFromWhere(list); // HOW TO DO?
//
// apply the same filter expression on another list
var result2 = list2.Where(conditions);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `list` variable is just a `List<T>` instance like any other, there is nothing you can get from it.

Comment: Perfect @IvanStoev!... Remember that is an example to explain the need. I need to get the LINQ expression from WHERE. The variable is only to illustrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence, what DynamicLinq does for you here is to parse the `string` you're passing in (along with the arguments) into an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.

So, in order to have the desired `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` stored in a variable, you can do this:

```
var conditions = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<ENTITY, bool>("Field1 = @0 AND Field2 >= @1", arg1, arg2);
```

(Where `ENTITY` is your entity type)

Then use it:

```
var result2 = list2.Where(conditions);
```

Also, in case `list2` is no longer an `IQueryable<ENTITY>` but an `IEnumerable<ENTITY>`, you'll have to compile the `Expression` into `Func<ENTITY, bool>` as follows:

```
var result2 = list2.Where(conditions.Compile());
```

See [Source](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DynamicLinq/System.Linq.Dynamic/Dynamic.cs)

Answer (score 1):

While it's unlikely that you could resolve the expression that was used on a list after it has already been executed, you could consider storing the expression and using it in multiple locations :

```
Expression<Func<ServerProductClass, bool>> conditions = BuildWhereExpression();
```

Where your `BuildWhereExpression()` method looked something like the following and would generate the necessary expression :

```
public Expression<Func<ServerProductClass, bool>> BuildExpression(string predicate, object[] terms)
{
     return DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<ServerProductClass, bool>(predicate, terms);
}
```

So your entire code might look something like this :

```
// Build your condition
var condition = BuildExpression("Field1 = @0 AND Field2 >= @2", new object[]{arg1, arg2 });

// Filter your initial list
list = list.Where(condition).ToList();

// Use it again later
var list2 = someOtherList.Where(condition).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// get the LINQ expression from WHERE
// Entity => your type of items in server1Products
Expression<Func<Entity, int>> conditions = x => x.Field1 == arg1 && x.Field2 = arg2;


// apply the same filter expression on another list
var result2 = list2.Where(conditions);
```